# Why can't primary RNA be used as a direct template for a protein?

Tags: dna

Why can't primary RNA be used as a direct template for a protein

Comment: Please explain what you mean by primary RNA. This is not a standard term in molecular biology.  Preferably add a reference or quotation so it is quite clear. Also, what do you mean by "Why"? Mechanistically or philosophically/logically?

Comment: *"Primary RNA transcript"* is a well known term in molecular biology. OP may have forgotten the *"transcript"* at the end, but it is quite obvious to me what they are asking.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado then you might want to edit the question for the rest of us.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I think half the problem with bad answers on this site is unclear questions. This is bad in many ways. Not only those I have indicated, but also that the poster has shown no evidence of having tried to solve this himself as described in the [help](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Furthermore, if he is asking about eukaryotes and his question is "why exons?" (philosophical) then he should have searched the site. The question would be a [duplicate](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/why-do-eukaryotic-organisms-have-introns-in-their-dna).

Comment: @a.baldwin Is this question about alternative splicing? Similar to the other commentators requests, please edit so no-one on SE has to guess what you are asking and you shall get answers :)