# Study on Introns?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, gene-expression, gene

I am curious whether there has been a study done on the effects of removing introns. Specifically, what happens if you genetically edit a eukaryote genome to no longer contain introns? Or maybe just a specific gene where the introns don't overlap with exons depending on splicing. Has any such study been conducted?

Comment: Have you read up on the roles that introns play in eukaryotes?  To start you could look at a [related question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1724/) on this site and then follow "Related" links from there. What can you conclude from that information?  In general, we encourage you to do some research on your own and then ask questions informed by what you have learned (ideally with references to reliable sources).  ——— You may also wish to consult the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and then edit your question accordingly. Thanks! 

Comment: The answer is yes of course, and you can find papers on the topic by a simple internet search.